# Access Denied in .NET writing file to file share

Tags: c#, .net, file, iis

I have a web service that is trying to write a file to a file share.

The application pool for the site in iis is running as a custom domain account: "domain\domainaccount"

I'm operating under the assumption and hope that when the code tries to write the file it will use the "domain\domainaccount" user to do so.

Executing the following line of code produces the error: `Access to the path [filename] is denied`

`FileStream stream = File.Create(fileName, result.Length);`

I have confirmed that the "domain\domainaccount" account has access to [filename] which is the full path of the file including the file name. I have even given the account access from the very top of the share structure, not just the specific folder the file needs to be written to. In fact, if I run notepad as "domain\domainaccount" I can save a file to that exact location.

What might I be doing incorrectly? Is it not using the domain account to write the file? If not, can I change something so that it does?

I should note that if I log into the iis server and run the web service from there, I do not get the access denied message and the file is created.

Comment: I'm with you that it should run using the credentials defined in the application pool. If you look at w3wp.exe in the Task Manager on the server, which identity is it using? [This post](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities) has some good information on configuring identities correctly.

Comment: There are two processes under that name (there are multiple sites on this server) but one if them does say the "domain\domainuser" account that I'm using.

Comment: I read the article and it talks about using applicationpoolidentity and networkservice, but doesn't talk about the set up for using a custom domain account. This iis set up and account set up are not new, they have been in production for a couple years, however, this is just the first time I am trying to write a file to the network share.

Comment: Does that account have domain administrator rights? If not, can you give it domain administrator rights (perhaps only momentarily) and see if that helps? And if it does, but you don't want it to have domain administrator rights, then try giving that account some of the rights that can be assigned via Control Panel - Administrative Tools - Local Security Policy - Local Policies - User Rights Assignment, and see if that is the magic incantation.

Comment: So what we found was that iis was passed the web user's credentials through to the file share, rather than using the credentials of the application pool. Not sure how iss determines if it should pass the user credentials through or use the application pool custom account.